# Function within while loop not running more than once

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a small game as a way to try and learn python. At the bottom of my code, there is a while loop which asks for user input. If that user input is yes, it is supposed to update a variable, encounter_prob. If encounter_prob is above 20, it is supposed to call the function. I can get this behavior to happen, but only once. It seems to not be going through the if statement again.

```
import random

def def_monster_attack():
    monster_attack = random.randrange(1,6)
    return monster_attack

def def_player_attack():
    player_attack = random.randrange(1,7)
    return player_attack

def def_encounter_prob():
    encounter_prob = random.randrange(1,100)
    return encounter_prob

def def_action():
    action = raw_input("Move forward? Yes or No")
    return action

player = {
    'hp': 100,
    'mp': 100,
    'xp': 0,
    'str': 7
    }

monster = {
    'hp': 45,
    'mp': 10,
    'str': 6
    }

def encounter():
    while player['hp'] > 0 and monster['hp'] > 0:

        keep_fighting = raw_input("Attack, Spell, Gaurd, or Run?")
        if keep_fighting.startswith('a') == True:
            player_attack = def_player_attack()
            monster['hp'] = monster['hp'] - player_attack
            monster_attack = def_monster_attack()
            player['hp'] = player['hp'] - monster_attack
            print "player's hp is", player['hp']
            print "monster's hp is", monster['hp']

while player['hp'] > 0:
    action = def_action()

    if action.startswith('y') == True:
        encounter_prob = def_encounter_prob()
        if encounter_prob > 20:
            encounter()
```

Comment: If `encounter()` sets `player['hp']` less than `1`, the `while` loop will not repeat.

Comment: It seems to be repeating. It just does not ever produce a second encounter.

Comment: `encounter()` exits when the condition in its `while` loop is not met. The next time you call it, neither of those values have changed, so it won't go back into the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually calling the function `encounter` twice but the first time ends up killing the monster by decreasing its `hp` to 0 or below, while the second time the function exits without entering the `while` loop because the `monster['hp'] > 0` comparison evaluates to `False`. The monster's `hp` aren't reset at each new encounter.

If you're having difficulties debugging your code, do not hesitate to put some `print` statements in different places to examine the value of your data. This should help you pinpointing what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code with a couple of print commands to show you how they can let you see what is going on, when you haven't finished all of your coding.
Oh! and I evened things up a bit, can't have you with an unfair advantage :)

```
import random

def def_monster_attack():
    monster_attack = random.randrange(1,7)
    return monster_attack

def def_player_attack():
    player_attack = random.randrange(1,7)
    return player_attack

def def_encounter_prob():
    encounter_prob = random.randrange(1,100)
    return encounter_prob

def def_action():
    action = raw_input("Move forward? Yes or No")
    return action

player = {
    'hp': 45,
    'mp': 100,
    'xp': 0,
    'str': 7
    }

monster = {
    'hp': 45,
    'mp': 10,
    'str': 6
    }

def encounter():
    while player['hp'] > 0 and monster['hp'] > 0:
        keep_fighting = raw_input("Attack, Spell, Guard, or Run?")
        if keep_fighting.startswith('a') == True:
            player_attack = def_player_attack()
            monster['hp'] = monster['hp'] - player_attack
            monster_attack = def_monster_attack()
            player['hp'] = player['hp'] - monster_attack
            print "It's a carve up! Your health", player['hp']," the monster's ", monster['hp']
        else:
            print "Try attacking!"
while player['hp'] > 0 and monster['hp'] > 0:
    action = def_action()

    if action.startswith('y') == True:
        encounter_prob = def_encounter_prob()
        if encounter_prob > 20:
            encounter()
        else:
            print "Nothing happened all seems well"
    else:
        print "What are you going to stand there all day"
    if player['hp'] < 1: print "Oops! You're dead!"
    if monster['hp'] < 1: print "Hurrah! The monster's dead"
```

Comment: Hahaha. I like the additions at the bottom :)